# Replace / translate characters in a string

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have a data frame with a character column:

```
df <- data.frame(var1 = c("aabbcdefg", "aabbcdefg"))
df
#        var1
# 1 aabbcdefg
# 2 aabbcdefg
```

I want to replace several different individual characters, e.g. from "a" to "h", from "b" to "i" and so on. Currently I use several calls to `gsub`:

```
df$var1 <- gsub("a", "h", df$var1)
df$var1 <- gsub("b", "i", df$var1)
df$var1 <- gsub("c", "j", df$var1)
df$var1 <- gsub("d", "k", df$var1)
df$var1 <- gsub("e", "l", df$var1)
df$var1 <- gsub("f", "m", df$var1)
df
#        var1
# 1 hhiijklmg
# 2 hhiijklmg
```

However, I'm sure there are more elegant solutions. Any ideas ho to proceed?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can create `from` and `to` vectors:

```
from <- c('a','b','c','d','e','f')
to <- c('h','i','j','k','l','m')
```

and then vectorialize the `gsub` function:

```
gsub2 <- function(pattern, replacement, x, ...) {
for(i in 1:length(pattern))
x <- gsub(pattern[i], replacement[i], x, ...)
x
}
```

Which gives:

```
> df <- data.frame(var1 = c("aabbcdefg", "aabbcdefg"))
> df$var1 <- gsub2(from, to, df$var1)
> df
       var1
1 hhiijklmg
2 hhiijklmg
```

Comment: @jrara How should I modify the code to make replacement conditionally? In the following example, I want to replace Mech, Oper and Eng, only when they are shortened, and I don't want to replace them inside the complete words (i.e. not Mech in Mechanical, or Oper in Operations) Here is the example:                     `from <- ("Mech", "Oper", "Eng")                                   to <- ("Mechanical", "Operations", "Engineer")                data.frame(var1 = c("Mech", "Mechanical Engineer", "Oper", "Operations"))`

Comment: Should be a standard function, Great!

Answer (score 39):

You want `chartr`:

```
df$var1 <- chartr("abcdef", "hijklm", df$var1)
df
#        var1
# 1 hhiijklmg
# 2 hhiijklmg
```

Answer (score 11):

If you don't want to use chartr because the substitutions may be more than one character, then another option is to use gsubfn from the gsubfn package (I know this is not gsub, but is an expansion on gsub).  Here is one example:

```
> library(gsubfn)
> tmp <- list(a='apple',b='banana',c='cherry')
> gsubfn('.', tmp, 'a.b.c.d')
[1] "apple.banana.cherry.d"
```

The replacement can also be a function that would take the match and return the replacement value for that match.