# similar Oracle TRANSLATE command in R

Tags: r, plsql, dplyr

Is any similar/analog Oracle TRANSLATE command in R environment? Need to change specific chars to numbers:

```
ORACLE way: TRANSLATE('XQWERTY','QWXY','1234')
Result: '312ERT4'
```

What could be similar in R?

Comment: `chartr('QWXY','1234','XQWERTY')` - thought this had to be a dup, but I can't find a perfect one for the life of me. Maybe - https://stackoverflow.com/a/6954528/496803 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13503848/replace-letters-with-ciphertext-ones/13504417

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a standard function `chartr`. Notice that the order of arguments is slightly different than in `TRANSLATE`.

```
chartr("QWXY", "1234", "XQWERTY")

result: "312ERT4"
```