# Importing data with special characters in R

Tags: r, csv, character-encoding, special-characters

The following pic shows how the data is before i import it(notepad) in R and after importing.

[image]

I use the following command to import it in R:

```
Data <- read.csv('data.csv',stringsAsFactors = FALSE,header = TRUE,quote = "")
```

It can be  seen that the special characters such as the ae is replaced with something like A| (line 19 on the left,line 18 or the right). Is there a way to import the CSV file as it is? (Using R)

Comment: Have you tried `install.packages("data.table");library(data.table);fread()`?

Comment: If you know the encoding type you can set that in the argument in readLines.

Comment: @dc3 the data are from web scraping, so I guess they dont have a standard format. Right? Or could be?

Comment: @MpizosDimitris correct - often you can check the encoding type (depending what browser you are using). Since its not in English, you'd have to look up what encoding is their most common... if you can't figure this out, there is always the option of finding the patterns and just gsubbing. - maybe this helps: http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-utf8.html#findcharset

Comment: I had an issue not dissimilar to this a while back. Some of the suggestions I received may be of help in terms of narrowing down the source of the error:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23152861/reading-foreign-characters

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Following ur suggestions for the encoding type I managed the solution by doing the following:Encoding(Data$Column) <- "UTF-8"

Answer (score 9):

Your problem is an encoding issue.  There are two aspects to this:  First, what is saved by Notepad++ may not correspond to the encoding that you are expecting in the saved text file, and second, R may be reading the file in using `read.csv()` based on a different encoding, which is especially possible since if you are using Notepad++ then this suggests you are using Windows, and therefore you may be unable to have UTF-8 as your system locale for R.

So taking each issue in turn:

1. *Getting Notepad++ to save your file in a specific encoding*.  Here you can set your encoding for the new file based using [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090845/change-the-default-encoding-for-notepad).  I always use UTF-8 but here since your texts are Danish, Latin-1 should work too.

   To verify the encoding of your texts, you may wish to use the `file` utility supplied with [RTools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/index.html).  This will tell you something about the probable encoding of your file from the command line, although it is not perfect.  (OS X and Linux users already have this without needing to install additional utilities.)
2. *Setting encoding when importing the .csv file into R.*  When you import the file using `read.csv()`, specify `encoding = "UTF-8"` or `encoding = "Latin-1"`.  You might also want to check though what your system encoding is, and match that.  You can do this with `Sys.getlocale()` (and set it with `Sys.setlocale()`.)  On my system for instance:

   ```
   > Sys.getlocale()
   [1] "en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8"
   ```

   You could of course set this to Windows-1252 but you might have trouble then with portability if using this on other platforms.  UTF-8 is the best solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I use only the parameter [encoding = "Latin-1"] and it worked. Thanks.

```
read.csv(paste(src,sprintf("%s.csv",x), sep = "/"), header = TRUE,
                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE, encoding = "Latin-1")
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31120284)