# convert unicode characters in italic or bold to normal characters using R

Tags: r, encoding, character-encoding

I have this string:

```
string <- "Blah blah \U0001d617\U0001d622\U0001d63a\U0001d633\U0001d630\U0001d62d\U0001d62d \U0001d61a\U0001d631\U0001d626\U0001d624\U0001d62a\U0001d622\U0001d62d\U0001d62a\U0001d634\U0001d635 blah blah"
```

when I pass it to cat i get this:

```
cat("Blah blah \U0001d617\U0001d622\U0001d63a\U0001d633\U0001d630\U0001d62d\U0001d62d \U0001d61a\U0001d631\U0001d626\U0001d624\U0001d62a\U0001d622\U0001d62d\U0001d62a\U0001d634\U0001d635 blah blah")
> Blah blah   blah blah
```

How can I convert the string into this:

```
> "Blah blah Payroll Specialist blah blah"
```

I have looked at this post: [R: Replacing foreign characters in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17517319/r-replacing-foreign-characters-in-a-string), but I can't make it work.

The problem arises when I pull data from a webservice, so ideally the solution I am looking for is a solution that handles many/all possible ways to represent the letters. (e.g. bold, italic, etc.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is library [stringi](https://github.com/gagolews/stringi) (`install.packages("stringi")`) with [`stri_trans_nf*` functions](https://rdrr.io/cran/stringi/man/stri_trans_nf.html)  (*Perform or Check For Unicode Normalization*); check [normalization forms for Unicode text](https://unicode.org/reports/tr15/) for theory.

```
string <- "Blah blah \U0001d617\U0001d622\U0001d63a\U0001d633\U0001d630\U0001d62d\U0001d62d \U0001d61a\U0001d631\U0001d626\U0001d624\U0001d62a\U0001d622\U0001d62d\U0001d62a\U0001d634\U0001d635 blah blah"
library(stringi)
stri_trans_nfkc(string)  # [1] "Blah blah Payroll Specialist blah blah"
stri_trans_nfkd(string)  # [1] "Blah blah Payroll Specialist blah blah"
```

Comment: Hi JosefZ. Thanks a lot!