# How to replace hebrew characters to NA in R

Tags: r, na

I have a table which some columns have values of Unknown but in Hebrew ("לא ידוע") where I try to replace those values with NA.

I have seen in other answers uses of functions like:

```
replace_with_na_a
```

or:

```
df [df == "לא ידוע"] <- NA
```

But none of them succeeded.
Is there a way to replace them?

---

I would like to point out that I did the actions that translate the table into Hebrew:

```
write.csv(dataset,"D:/Doctorate/Courses/R/data_intro_r_test.csv", row.names = FALSE)

#Read & read the Hebrew in the table
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "Hebrew")
sample.data <- read_csv(file = "data_intro_r_test.csv",
                        locale = locale(date_names = "he", encoding = "UTF-8"))
line=readLines("D:/Doctorate/Courses/R/data_intro_r_test.csv", encoding = "UTF-8")
iconv(line, "ISO-8859-8", "UTF-8")
```

Thank you,
Maya

Comment: Already checked [these](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17517319/6574038) solutions?

Comment: If you know of a particular location that has that string, maybe test compared to it?  E.g. if entry 1 of column 2 has it, use `df[df == df[1,2]] <- NA`.

Comment: @maya has this helped you further along?

Comment: yes very much! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We have to assess which columns in `df` are of class `character`. Then, replace all character strings in those columns that do *not* contain letters from the Latin alphabet with `NA`.

```
df <- data.frame(
  numbers = rnorm(n = 4L),
  factor = gl(2L, 2L, labels = c('male', 'female')),
  string = c('I', 'use', 'regex', 'לא ידוע')
)
ncX <- ncol(df)
for (i in seq_len(ncX)) {
  if (class(df[, i]) %in% 'character') {
    df[, i] <- gsub('[^a-zA-Z]', NA, df[, i])
  } else next
}
```

```
> df
     numbers factor string
1  0.9352600   male      I
2 -0.5864270   male    use
3 -0.6104655 female  regex
4  0.3481119 female   <NA>
```